# JQuery hover function select all elements with same class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Need to highlight the current hovered element + all other elements with same colour / class name.

Example here:

https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/LkaYOW

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.orange-cell, .green-cell, .purple-cell, .white-cell').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
    },function() {
        $(this).removeClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Currently only highlights one element when hovering. Need some help with the jQuery selector so that all elements of the same colour get the class 'z-relative'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the changes needed for your code.

HTML CHanges:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cell orange-cell" data-color="orange">Home</li>
    <li class="cell green-cell" data-color="green">About</li>
    <li class="cell purple-cell" data-color="purple">Contact</li>
    <li class="cell white-cell" data-color="white">Num</li>
</ul>

<h1>Some text here</h1>

<ul>
    <li class="cell orange-cell" data-color="orange">Home</li>
    <li class="cell green-cell" data-color="green">About</li>
    <li class="cell purple-cell" data-color="purple">Contact</li>
    <li class="cell white-cell" data-color="white">Num</li>
</ul>

<h1>Some text here</h1>

<ul>
    <li class="cell orange-cell" data-color="orange">Home</li>
    <li class="cell green-cell" data-color="green">About</li>
    <li class="cell purple-cell" data-color="purple">Contact</li>
    <li class="cell white-cell" data-color="white">Num</li>
</ul>

<div id="darkness"></div>
```

JS Changes :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.orange-cell, .green-cell, .purple-cell, .white-cell').hover(function() {
        var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
        $("."+color+"-cell").addClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
    },function() {var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
        $("."+color+"-cell").removeClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works fine but I was trying to avoid adding additional html markup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to  change html you can do like this.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.orange-cell, .green-cell, .purple-cell, .white-cell').hover(function() {
        var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        $("."+colorClass ).addClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
    },function() {var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];;
        $("."+colorClass ).removeClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works with no change to my HTML markup.
Trying to follow what you are doing with the variable 'colorClass'. 
You make the variable with 'this', then split it, then concatenate + addClass?

Two other points:
1). Do we need to rewrite the same variable
2). Guessing the ;; is a typo?

Thank you

Comment: 1) yes, because $(this) will give corresponding element each time. 2) Ya its typo error. you can accept answer if its help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. One thing that you need to note here that you need to always add color class (green-cell,orange-cell) at second place inside your li tag

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var highlitedClass;
    $('.orange-cell, .green-cell, .purple-cell, .white-cell').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('z-relative');
        var liClass = $(this).prop("class");
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
        liClass = liClass.split(' ');
        highlitedClass = liClass[1];
        $("." + highlitedClass).addClass('z-relative');

    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('z-relative');
        $("." + highlitedClass).removeClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```